# Capistrano Nginx and Puma Deploy to ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, capistrano3, puma

I just deployed my app to Ubuntu 14.04 with Capistrano with these files
Gemfile

```
  gem 'capistrano', '3.5.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-nginx'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-db'
  gem 'capistrano-rails-console'
  gem 'capistrano-upload-config'
  gem 'sshkit-sudo'
```

And I did few steps as they were mention in a vidoe tutorial, for creating files and everything my deploy.erb is.

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.5.0'

set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:evercam/evercam-admin.git'
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

set :user, 'deployer'
set :application, 'evercam-admin'
set :rails_env, 'production'
server '88.99.226.17', user: "#{fetch(:user)}", roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :pty, true

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/puma.rb')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads')

set :config_example_suffix, '.example'
set :config_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/config/puma.rb"

namespace :deploy do
  before 'check:linked_files', 'config:push'
  before 'check:linked_files', 'puma:config'
  before 'check:linked_files', 'puma:nginx_config'
  after 'puma:smart_restart', 'nginx:restart'
end
```

After a successful deploy, my application First started on `88.99.226.17` And I got low level errors and In logs there was errors about secret_key_base, I added that and deployed again but now THe app not even loading on that public IP. 
Nginx logs are fine there is nothing in error log for nginx and my configuration file is https://github.com/evercam/evercam-admin/blob/master/config/deploy/templates/nginx_conf.erb

Please help I have already spent a huge amount of time on this. . Thanks in advance,

Comment: not sure if you ever solved this problem, but for future endeavors posting a stack trace from `cap production deploy doctor` can real helpful for other people in troubleshooting your issue.